# How to cite page number as :XX rather than p.XX?

Tags: pandoc

How can I configure Pandoc to display the citation `[@smith2014, p.751]` as "(Smith 2014:751)" rather than as "(Smith 2014, p. 751)"?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify any CSL stylesheet (ie from [this repo](https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles)) using the `--csl=[file]` flag.